# Example of a non-Jordan region

Tags: linear-algebra

As a quick reminder: a Jordan region $M$ is a compact space with its boundary $\partial M$ being a null set. (vol($\partial M$)$ = 0$)

However, I have a hard time trying to find a compact space in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a boundary that isn't a null set. It seems like a surface intrinsically being 2 dimensional in a 3 dimensional space, is always fitting in the definition of a null set.

Does anyone have a simple example of a non-Jordan region?

Edit: excluding examples of non-compact sets.

Answer (score 0):

Take $M=C\times C\times C$ where $C$ is Cantor set with positive measure. The set $M$ is compact. Suppose that $M$ has nonempty interior. Then there exists a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in M$ and $\varepsilon >0$ such that $(x_0 -\varepsilon , x_0 +\varepsilon)\times (y_0 -\varepsilon , y_0 +\varepsilon)\times (z_0 -\varepsilon , z_0 +\varepsilon)\in M ,$

now define $\pi_x : \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R} $ by $$\pi_x ((x,y,z))=x$$ then $$(x_0 -\varepsilon , x_0 +\varepsilon ) \subset \pi_x (M) =C$$
but this is impossible since $C$ has empty interior.

So the set $M$ a compact set with empty interior hence $\partial M =M $ and thus $$\mu (\partial M ) =\mu (M) =\mu (C\times C\times C) =(\mu (C) )^3 >0,$$
since $C$ had a positive measure.